# kubectl exec on a windows container in AKS does nothing (jenkins also can't execute commands in the running container)

Tags: windows, kubernetes, jenkins, kubectl, azure-aks

We have a jenkins instance running in AKS and it works fine using linux based images for build pods. Now we're trying to add a Windows nodepool as well (windows 2022) so that we can run jobs that require windows-based images for the build.

I've already successfully created a servercore2022 based jenkins inbound agent image (not officially done yet unfortunately, but it works - 2022 version is required by our build), and everything seems to be fine, until I actually try to run a pipeline that wants to execute a bat or powershell command. Then the build hangs until I abort it. No error messages, nothing.

Added logging and I got to a point where I see what it tries to execute in the windows container, it is something like this:

```
Jul 07, 2023 11:35:32 AM FINEST org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pipeline.ContainerExecDecorator
Executing command: cmd /c ""/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/TestBuild@tmp/durable-211dc6c4/jenkins-wrap.bat"" 
[47 μs.]
Jul 07, 2023 11:35:32 AM INFO org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pipeline.ContainerExecDecorator$1 doLaunch
Created process inside pod: [testbuild-66-k9kt9-j47xf-gff47], container: [msbuild][288 ms]
Jul 07, 2023 11:35:32 AM FINEST org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pipeline.ContainerExecDecorator
onClose : java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch@6e12ee2e[Count = 0] [234 ms]
```

After that it just hangs, no logs in the containers either.
So, I've tried to run the command from my local machine using kubectl, and it is very weird, because if I run it from PowerShell, it executes correctly, and the jenkins build console output will show the result and jenkins will recognize that the command ran successfully and the job will finish successfully.
However, if I try the same from git bash it just prints a windows prompt, exits and the command is not executed... I'm at a loss, looks like it is a bug in kubernetes somehow? I found no such limitation listed anywhere and according to documentation this should just work, but it doesn't.
The container is clearly working since it executes from PowerShell I'd expect that it could just be a syntax difference, but I don't think it is, I tried a few variations with different quote usage and escaping and nothing worked, I could only make it worse where it provided an error message, but I never could get the actual batch file to execute from bash.

Here are the runs from Powershell,

```
╭─ pwsh
╰─ﬀ kubectl exec testbuild-63-mvjvm-grr2t-5nq4f --container msbuild -- cmd /c ""/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/TestBuild@tmp/durable-24126237/jenkins-wrap.bat""
╭─ pwsh
╰─ﬀ
```

and git bash:

```
╭─ bash
╰─ﬀ kubectl exec -t -q testbuild-66-k9kt9-j47xf-gff47 --container msbuild -- cmd /c ""/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/TestBuild@tmp/durable-211dc6c4/jenkins-wrap.bat""
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.20348.1726]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\>╭─ bash
╰─ﬀ
```

Here is the jenkinsfile for the test build:

```
@Library('jenkins-shared-lib')_

pipeline {

    options {
        ansiColor('xterm')
        timestamps()
    }

    agent {
        kubernetes {
          cloud 'kubernetes'
          defaultContainer 'jnlp'
          showRawYaml false
          yaml '''
            apiVersion: v1
            kind: Pod
            metadata:
              name: windows
              namespace: jenkins
              labels:
                run: jnlp
            spec:
              os:
                name: windows
              nodeSelector:
                agentpool: devjkw
                kubernetes.io/os: windows
              containers:
                - name: jnlp
                  image: <redacted>.azurecr.io/jenkins-inbound-agent-windowsservercore-ltsc2022:1.0
                  tty: true
                - name: msbuild
                  image: <redacted>.azurecr.io/win2022-servercore-buildtools-git-gh-win10sdk-inno:1.0
                  command:
                  - powershell
                  args:
                  - Start-Sleep
                  - 999999
              imagePullSecrets:
                - name: project-acr-secret
          '''.stripIndent().trim()
       }
    }
    
    stages {

        stage('Prepare') {
            steps {
                script {
                    System.setProperty("org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.WindowsBatchScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS", "true");
                }
                buildDescription("""
                    Test Build
                """)
            }
        }

        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                container('msbuild') {
                  bat 'dir'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Update:<br>

it seems like there are two problems when running the command from bash:


1. The `-- cmd /c ...` part WILL NOT work because everything after "cmd" is just ignored. Hence it just executes cmd (which produces the output I've pasted above) and then exits normally. If I however write:
`-- cmd -/c ...` it works. I've not found this anywhere in any docs, but it's the same way in docker and kubectl.


2. Paths are weird. It requires me to prepend the path with /c/... otherwise it will prepend by itself with C:/Program Files and then complain about the space...